# Script-Run Silverlight Test Project

Tags: silverlight, testing, scripting, automation, silverlight-5.0

I have a solution with several Silverlight Test Projects. I would like to have some kind of script or tool with the ability of running all these test projects and generating some kind of report (any simple output will work)

I googled around for some time but I was unable to find any existent solution other than running the projects one by one from Visual Studio.

Has someone came across this situation before? Any idea on how to implement such a tool?

Regards

Comment: does my solution work for you?

Comment: @NickNieslanik sorry for the delay, i have to give it a test drive and i should have the results by the end of the week. thanks for your time :)

Comment: sounds good.  Let me know if you have any questions about it.  I've implemented it with powershell wrappers and also within a TFS build workflow and it's working pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

If you need automated testing then Test Manager is a tool from Microsoft. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/test-professional/overview
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385901.aspx
and use with silverlight
http://jugalpanchal.blogspot.com/2011/09/configure-test-manager-for-silverlight.html

Answer (score 0):

Use StatLight!  http://statlight.codeplex.com  It's a Silverlight Test Project runner exe that you can invoke from the cmdline.  Its great and can be integrated into TFS Workflows as well as Msbuild.